# which version of android OS is 4G compatible?

Tags: 4g, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I am still using 2.3.6 release and about to upgrade 4.2 jelly bean. Does any release provide 4G enabled OS so that i can use 4G data in my mobile.

If no is there any 3rd party application which can do my work.

my handset : samsung S advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes a difference which Android version you use: the support for 4G is provided by the cell radio drivers, added to the system by the manufacturer.

The Samsung Galaxy S Advance does not have the hardware needed to use 4G networks, so upgrading the OS won't add this support, and there's no way a third-party app can do that either. If you want a phone with 4G, you just have to buy a phone with 4G.